# Capture and monitor the request of the flash client to the server

Tags: flash, networking, network-programming, gamekit

I want to make an auto-play for some flash-based web-game, but I don't know how to capture and monitor the request from the flash client to the server.
Can anyone help me solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use FireBug or a debugging proxy like Charles. Flash's requests will show up like normal HTTP requests.